# Customize Blizcharts tooltip in React

Tags: reactjs, charts, tooltip

I'm using a chart from BlizCharts on a React Component and I want to change how the tooltip looks, but I cant really figure it out. I tried adding styles but nothing changed.

this is my code:

```
<Box>
           
            <Box display='flex' justifyContent='space-between'>
                <p
                    style={{
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed, sans-serif',
                        marginBottom: '.5rem',
                    }}
                >
                    {props.title}
                </p>
                <Box>
                    <DownloadButton                 
                    />
                </Box>
            </Box>
            <Box></Box>

            {data && (
                <StackedBarChart
                    onGetG2Instance={(chartInstance) => {
                        setCanvas(chartInstance.chart.canvas);
                    }}
                    id='StackedBarChart'
                    data={data}
                    height={650}
                    autoFit
                    legend={{ position: 'bottom', flipPage: false }}
                    yField={props.yField}
                    xField={props.xField}
                    stackField={props.stackField}
                    padding='auto'
                    color={['red', '#00A1C8', '#B3CEE7', '#808080']}
                    tooltip={{
                        
                        formatter: (d) => {
                            return {
                                name: d['Pesticide region'] ? d['Pesticide region'] : d.region,
                                value:
                                    (d['Region proportion per country']
                                        ? d['Region proportion per country']
                                        : d.value) + '%',
                            };
                        },
                    }}
                    yAxis={{
                        label: {
                            style: {
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed, sans-serif',
                            },
                        },
                    }}
                    xAxis={{
                        label: {
                            style: {
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed, sans-serif',
                            },
                            formatter: (a, b, c) => {
                                return a + '%';
                            },
                        },
                        max: 100,
                    }}
                />
            )}
        </Box>
```

And i tried adding this code inside tooltip, before the formatter line,  but it doesnt seem to work :

```
style: {
        fill: 'red',
        backgroundColor: '#000',
   },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if anyone else is searching for the answer, I found it here : https://bizcharts.taobao.com/product/BizCharts4/category/62/page/80#itemtpl

- You can make your own template by using their library.
  example:

```
  containerTpl= '<div class="g2-tooltip">'
  + '<div class="g2-tooltip-title" style="margin-bottom: 4px;"></div>'
  + '<ul class="g2-tooltip-list"></ul>'
  + '</div>',
```

and you use this inside the tooltip :

```
<StackedBarChart
                    onGetG2Instance={(chartInstance) => {
                        setCanvas(chartInstance.chart.canvas);
                    }}
                    id='StackedBarChart'
                    data={data}
                    height={650}
                    autoFit
                    legend={{ position: 'bottom', flipPage: false }}
                    yField={props.yField}
                    xField={props.xField}
                    stackField={props.stackField}
                    padding='auto'
                    color={['red', '#00A1C8', '#B3CEE7', '#808080']}
                    tooltip={{
                          containerTpl= '<div class="g2-tooltip">'
  + '<div class="g2-tooltip-title" style="margin-bottom: 4px;"></div>'
  + '<ul class="g2-tooltip-list"></ul>'
  + '</div>',

                        formatter: (d) => {
                            return {
                                name: d['Pesticide region'] ? d['Pesticide region'] : d.region,
                                value:
                                    (d['Region proportion per country']
                                        ? d['Region proportion per country']
                                        : d.value) + '%',
                            };
                        },
                    }}
```